# How to have a DLL work on different Windows versions?

Tags: windows, com, dll

I'm compiling my own DLL comprised of several `.o` files.  One of the `.o` files has a function that calls `SHLoadLibraryFromItem` that is supported on Windows 7 only.  The function is never called unless the application that uses the DLL is running on Windows 7.  (Yes, I'm sure.)

However, when running the application on an older version of Windows (say, XP), the entire application crashes upon launch with an error "The specified procedure could not be found."  Although the error doesn't specify which procedure could not be found, if I comment out the call to `SHLoadLibraryFromItem`, then everything works fine.

Questions:

1. Why is Windows attempting to find `SHLoadLibraryFromItem` even though it's not being called on XP?
2. Is there any way to have Windows *not* do that, i.e., find `SHLoadLibraryFromItem` only when running Windows 7, i.e., some kind of lazy binding?
3. If not, what's the best way around this?

The only way's around this that I can think of are either:

1. Use `LoadLibrary` to load the Windows DLL that `SHLoadLibraryFromItem` is in and use `GetProcAddress` to obtain the address manually into a pointer-to-function and use the pointer to call `SHLoadLibraryFromItem` instead?
2. Have two DLLs: one that contains functions that are supported for Windows 7 that will be loaded only when running on Windows 7.

Any other ideas?  I'd really prefer some kind of lazy binding as mentioned above.

## Update

PLEASE READ WHAT I ACTUALLY WROTE.  I clearly stated in the first paragraph that  `SHLoadLibraryFromItem` is *not* called unless I KNOW FOR CERTAIN that the application ACTUALLY IS RUNNING ON WINDOWS 7.

The application crashes merely when the DLL is  *loaded*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The linker embeds a reference in your modules to every API function that's used.  when the Windows loader loads your executable and its modules, it needs to "hook up" all the calls in your code to the locations in memory where the API functions are actually loaded.  If it can't find them, it won't continue.

Using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` is the "standard" way to get around this problem.

Using two DLLs doesn't help you, because as long as one of them fails to load your app will still not start.  You could get around this by using delay-loading, putting all the code that depends on a new O/S in a separate module and wrapping all the calls to that module in Win32 SEH exception handlers (you get an SEH exception when delay-loading cannot load a module).  The advantage is that you can use the "automatic" linking without the mess of function pointers, but the exception handling can be pretty nasty.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/XDllPt4.aspx) explains a bit and gives some examples of how to wrap this up neatly.

Comment: You can't delay-load just individual symbols? (I'm used to being able to do this in ELF executables on Linux)

Comment: @Craig Ringer I don't think so, the delay-load parameter to the linker is a list of modules.  Technically, the linker could do it pretty easily, since it's generating a stub for each function, but I don't think there's any way to get it to do that.

Comment: @Craig Ringer Maybe I misunderstood your question... if the DLL is present, but one of the functions you referenced is not, the delay-load code generated by the linker should attempt each `GetProcAddress()` call separately, so the missing one would generate an exception, but the others would still work.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is Windows attempting to find
>   SHLoadLibraryFromItem even though it's
>   not being called on XP?

Windows resolves references when the application is loaded into memory, not when a call is made. This is called "dynamic linking" (as opposed to static linking with a Linker), but it is not truly dynamic. Therefore, it does not know whether the a particular method will be called during runtime or not.